# Removing query string parameter from Url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2

Coming from AngularJS I thought this would be easy enough in Vue.js 2 as well. But it seems this is difficult by design in Vue.

In AngularJS I can do this `$location.search('my_param', null);` which will effectively turn `https://mydomain.io/#/?my_param=872136` into `https://mydomain.io/#/`.

In Vue I have tried `this.$router.replace('my_param',null);`, but it will only do `https://mydomain.io/#/?my_param=872136` -> `https://mydomain.io/#/my_param`, leaving the empty **my_param**.

Isn´t there anyway in Vuejs2 to remove the query params from the Url? Should I resort to plain JS to achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`router.replace()` is to navigate by removing the current URL from the browser history stack and replace it with the argument route you pass to it.

The actual syntax is `router.replace(url_location, onComplete, onAbort)`.

What you are doing is `router.replace(my_param, null)` which is removing the current URL from the history stack and replacing it with `'my_param'` and for the `onComplete` callback you are passing a `null`

So do it like this:

```
this.$router.replace('/')
```

More info on [programatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: But how do I  determine which param it should delete? `this.$router.replace('/paramname')`??

Comment: For anyone who needs to clear only the query params without affecting the router stack, try this: `this.$router.replace({'query': null});`

Answer (score 24):

In the case that you have multiple query parameters the correct way to remove one of them would be:

```
const query = Object.assign({}, this.$route.query);
delete query.my_param;
this.$router.replace({ query });
```

Comment: This does not work if query object is empty. In that case you need to use {query: [];}

Answer (score 4):

@DaveIdito's answer given in a comment above has been valuable to me several times. Adding it as an answer in order to bring proper attention to it.

To only remove all of the the query params without loading again or changing history, use:

```
this.$router.replace({'query': null});
```

Comment: I found that this did reload the page. The created hooks ran again, which meant my code reacting to the query params ran again, going into the else as if the query param had never existed.

Answer (score 2):

Vue 3

If need to delete a particular query parameter. lets say `my_param`

```
const queryParams = { ...route.query };

delete queryParams.my_param;

router.replace({ query: queryParams });
```

If need to delete all query parameters

```
router.replace({ query: undefined });
```

Comment: note that `route.query` is mutable and has only been shallow copied with the spread operator, so this approach is mutating `route` and can cause unexpected problems (say, if you are using it in `beforeEach`...)

Answer (score 2):

Vue 3 & Vue Router 4. Clean way.

```
useRouter().push({ query: {} });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me pretty well. It replaces all the query parameter and just changes the route to path only.

> router.replace(route.path);